# Sections on a finite union of principal open subsets in affine $n$-space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is exercise 2.5.12 of Liu's Algebraic Geometry.

> Let $k$ be a field. Let $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^rD(f_i)$ be a finite union of principal open subsets of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$. Show that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(X) = k[T_1,\dots,T_n]_f$ where $f = \mathrm{gcd}(f_1,\dots,f_r)$.

Can anyone help me solve this? Thank you.

I have some progress:
First, note that $X \subset D(f)$. So we have restriction maps
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(D(f)) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(X) \to 
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(D(f_i))
$$
Since $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ is an integral scheme, all the above restriction maps are injective.
It suffices to show $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(D(f)) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(X)$ is
surjective. Because elements of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(X)$ is in one-to-one correspondence
with elements $(a_1,\dots,a_r) \in \prod_{i=1}^r\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(D(f_i))$ verifying
$a_i|_{D(f_if_j)} = a_j|_{D(f_if_j)}$ for all $i,j \in [r]$. So, it suffices to find $a \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(D(f))$
verifying $a|_D(f_i) = a_i$ for all $i \in [r]$.
Suppose $a_i = g_i/f_i^u \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^n}(D(f_i)) = k[T_1,\dots,T_n]_{f_i}$.
(Because there are finitely many $a_i$, $u$ can be chose independent of $i$).
$a_i|_{D(f_if_j)} = a_j|_{D(f_if_j)}$ then means
$$
\frac{g_if_j^u}{(f_if_j)^u} = \frac{g_jf_i^u}{(f_if_j)^u}, \quad \mathrm{i.e.,} \quad 
g_if_j^u = g_jf_i^u
$$
All the ring above can be thought of subrings of $k(T_1,\dots,T_n)$. So, in $k(T_1,\dots,T_n)$, we
have
$$
\frac{g_i}{f_i^u} = \frac{g_j}{f_j^u}
$$
**Here I got stuck. I cannot find $g/f^l$ to represent $g_i/f_i^u$ simultaneously.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point that you are not using is that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ *is a UFD*.

Thus, any element $\alpha$ of $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ can be written in a unique way as a quotient $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a$ and $b$ having no common irreducible divisor and in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ (up to scalars).

Then, for any nonzero polynomial $g$, $\alpha \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_g$ iff $b$ divides some power of $g$, that is, if every irreducible factor of the denominator of $\alpha$ occurs in $g$.

Can you finish the proof using that?

Comment: Sorry, could you please be more specific?

Comment: Is your issue with the content of my post, or with how it can be used to deduce the final result?

Comment: How it can be used to deduce the final result?

Comment: By properties of integral schemes, $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is the intersection of the $R_i=\mathcal{O}(D(f_i))$. Now, $R_i$ is the subring of $\alpha \in k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that its denominator contains only irreducible factors of $f_i$. So $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is the subring of $\alpha \in k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that all the irreducible factors of its denominator occur in each $f_i$. But this is equivalent (by UFD) to all the irreducible factors of the denominator of $\alpha$ to divide $f$, which is equivalent to $\alpha \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_f$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarafication. I think I got it. Also, from your point, if I assume $f_i,f_j$ are distinct irreducible (equivalent to prime in a UFD), then $g_jf_i^u = g_if_j^u$. Hence, $f_i \mid g_i$. So, we may assume $u = 0$, and $g_i/f_i^u$ glues to $g = g_1 = g_2=\dots=g_r$.

If $f_i$ are not irreducible, it's indeed difficult to write out their glueing explicitly.